# Plot Linetypes Rendering Differently on Linux vs. Mac OSX

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny

I'm having a problem with a Shiny app that I'm developing and hosting on a DigitalOcean server. The linetypes in the plots rendered in the Shiny app appear differently based on whether I'm running my application locally or running it on the DigitalOcean (Linux, Ubuntu) server.

My setup for hosting a Shiny app on DigitalOcean is based off of [these instructions](https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/).

Screenshot from the Linux (Ubuntu) server with the bad linetypes:
[image: Plot with weird linetypes from Linux server]

Screenshot from running the app locally (on Mac OSX) with correct linetypes:
[image: Plot with normal linetypes from running my Shiny server on Mac OS X]

Has anybody else run into this issue, and if so, has anybody else found a solution for fixing the discrepancy?

In particular, the plots from my Mac OS X system are correct, whereas the plots from the Linux server are incorrect. The really short gaps between the dashes in the Linux version make it more difficult to read...

I wanted to add a minimum reproducible example to the best of my ability. Here's an example of an app that has this problem when I run it on the Ubuntu server I have at DigitalOcean vs. locally.

ui.R

```
    fluidPage(
      headerPanel('example plot'),
      plotOutput('plot1')
    )
```

server.R

```
    library(magrittr)
    library(reshape2)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)

    function(input, output, session) {

      WorldPhones %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        tibble::rownames_to_column('year') %>%
        reshape2::melt(variable.name='continent') %>%
        mutate(year = as.integer(year)) -> wp

      output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(wp, aes(x=year, y=value, color = continent, linetype = continent)) +
          geom_line()
      }, res=200)

    }
```

Has anybody else had any experience like this with plotting linetype discrepancies? Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an example of the plotting code you're using?

Comment: It should not be difficult to make a simple example that does not depend on a “closed source application. Voting to close as lacking [MCVE].